# Problems with TCP in VACaMobil

Tags: tcp, omnet++, veins

I am having some problems with TCP in VACaMobil. 
I am using two TCP modules built up in Inet: TCPBasicClientApp and TCPEchoApp.
The former works as a client and the former works as a server.

The number of cars (the module name is "coche") in the simulation is 100, and there are five concurrent transmissions:

```
CLIENT    SERVER
Car 0 --> Car 99
Car 1 --> Car 98
Car 2 --> Car 97
Car 3 --> Car 96
Car 4 --> Car 95
```

I am also using three routing protocols: AODV, DYMO and OLSR.
However, regardless of the configuration that I run, errors like this ocurr in the simulation:

```
Error in module (TCPBasicClientApp) Highway.coche[*].tcpApp[0] (id = 35) at event #49519, t = 166: IPvXAddressResolver: module 'coche[98]' not found.
```

In this case, using AODV, the car 1 cannot communicate with the car 98. I learned that VACaMobil, after a time, deletes some cars while it is creating others beyond 100, 
such as  "coche[110]", "coche[115]", etc.

I don't understand why it keeps deleting and creating nodes; I thought that VACaMobil really generated a constant number of vehicles.

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the omnetpp.ini:

```
[General]

network = Highway

debug-on-errors = false

cmdenv-express-mode = true
cmdenv-autoflush = true
cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s
#repeat = 10
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins
tkenv-image-path = bitmaps

check-signals = true

**.manager.**.scalar-recording = true
**.manager.**.vector-recording = true
**.manetrouting.**.scalar-recording = true
**.movStats.**.scalar-recording = true
**.movStats.**.vector-recording = true
**.mac.**.scalar-recording = true
**.mac.**.vector-recording = true
**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true

#ChannelControl
*.channelControl.carrierFrequency = 2.4GHz
*.channelControl.pMax = 2mW
*.channelControl.sat = -110dBm
*.channelControl.alpha = 2
*.channelControl.numChannels = 1

# TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd
*.manager.updateInterval = 1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.moduleType = "rcdp9.TAdhocHost"
*.manager.moduleName = "coche"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.margin = 25
*.manager.warmUpSeconds = 0
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("VACaMobil/Milan/downtown.launch.xml")
*.manager.getStatistics = true
*.manager.statFiles = "${resultdir}/${configname}-${runnumber}-"

# nic settings
**.wlan[*].bitrate = 24Mbps
**.wlan[*].opMode = "g"
**.wlan[*].mgmt.frameCapacity = 10
**.wlan[*].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc"
**.wlan[*].mac.basicBitrate = 24Mbps
**.wlan[*].mac.controlBitrate = 24Mbps
**.wlan[*].mac.address = "auto"
**.wlan[*].mac.maxQueueSize = 14
**.wlan[*].mac.rtsThresholdBytes = 3000B
**.wlan[*].mac.retryLimit = 7
**.wlan[*].mac.cwMinData = 7
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitterPower = 2mW
**.wlan[*].radio.thermalNoise = -110dBm
**.wlan[*].radio.sensitivity = -85dBm
**.wlan[*].radio.pathLossAlpha = 2
**.wlan[*].radio.snirThreshold = 4dB

**.channelNumber = 0

**.coche.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = "configurator"

# manet routing
**.routingProtocol = ${"AODVUU", "DYMO", "OLSR"}

**.tcpAlgorithmClass = "TCPNewReno"

**.coche[0..4].numTcpApps = 1
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPBasicClientApp"
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].localPort = -1
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].connectPort = 1000
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].dataTransferMode = "bytecount"
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].startTime = 10s
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].thinkTime = 1s
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].idleInterval = 3s
**.coche[0..4].tcpApp[*].requestLength = 5000000B

**.coche[5..94].numTcpApps = 0

**.coche[95..99].numTcpApps = 1
**.coche[95..99].tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPEchoApp"
**.coche[95..99].tcpApp[*].localPort = 1000
**.coche[95..99].tcpApp[*].dataTransferMode = "bytecount"

**.coche[0].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "coche[99]"
**.coche[1].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "coche[98]"
**.coche[2].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "coche[97]"
**.coche[3].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "coche[96]"
**.coche[4].tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "coche[95]"

**.meanNumberOfCars = 100
**.autoShutdown = false
```

Here is TAdhocHost.ned:

```
package rcdp9;

import inet.networklayer.IManetRouting;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.HostAutoConfigurator2;
import inet.nodes.inet.AdhocHost;

module TAdhocHost extends AdhocHost
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/cellphone");
        mobilityType = default("TraCIMobility");
        IPForward = true;
    submodules:
        ac_wlan: HostAutoConfigurator2 {
          @display("p=127,240");
        }
    connections:
}
```

Here is Highway.ned:

```
package rcdp9;

import inet.world.VACaMobil.VACaMobil;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.HostAutoConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.world.radio.ChannelControl;
import inet.world.traci.TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd;

network Highway
{
    submodules:
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=396,221");
        }
        channelControl: ChannelControl {
            @display("p=396,310");
        }
        manager: VACaMobil {
            @display("p=322,405");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, VACaMobil is built on Veins.

Veins creates a new network node for every vehicle that starts driving. When the corresponding vehicle stops driving (having arrived at its destination) Veins deletes the network node. It never re-uses the same node index.

Thus, in your example, the first vehicle that starts driving will be `coche[0]`. The next vehicle that starts driving will be `coche[1]` - independent of whether `coche[0]` already arrived or is still driving.